# Referencing Rows in Instance Variable

Tags: python, variables, instance

Apologies if this is answered elsewhere, but I cannot find (or maybe understand) anything that appears to be what I am trying to do...

I have a large-ish file with approx. 60000 rows and 136 columns. From this I want to extract about 20 columns and have created an instance variable to store the data. The data then gets parsed and cut according to entries in several of the columns and moved to new copies of the instance variable to maintain consistency. At the moment I am doing this for each column in the instance and I would like to copy a whole row at a time, but cannot find the way of referencing a row in an instance variable. Examples of what I am doing and would like to do are below.

If anyone could either point me in the right direction or suggest a better method of doing the same thing (instead of using an instance variable), I would be most grateful.

---

Instance Variable:

```
class Instance_Object:

###------------------------------------------------------------------
### __init__ Function to create the object
### 
###          Stores all the interesting parameters from the data 
###------------------------------------------------------------------

def __init__(self):

    self.a = []
    self.b = []
    self.c = []
    # etc
```

---

Current Main Code:

```
result = pyf.open(datapath+data_filename)
header = result[1].header
file_data = result[1].data

data_a, data_b = Instance_Object(), Instance_Object()

data_a.a = file_data.VAR1
data_a.b = file_data.VAR2
data_a.c = file_data.VAR3
#(etc)

for i in range(len(data_a.a)):
    if 0.0 <= data_a.a[i] <= 100.0: 
        if -1.0 <= data_a.b[i] <= 1.0:
            data_b.a.append(data_a.a[i])
            data_b.b.append(data_a.b[i])
            data_b.c.append(data_a.c[i])
            # etc
```

---

What I would like to do:

```
for i in range(len(data_a.a)):
    if 0.0 <= data_a.a[i] <= 100.0: 
        if -1.0 <= data_a.b[i] <= 1.0:
            data_b.append(data_a[i])
            # i.e. append the entire row from data_a into data_b whilst 
            # maintaining the structure
```

Comment: You may want to have a look at `numpy` and its (indexing capabilities)[http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html]. It allows you to do things like `a[(0 <= a) & (a <= 100) & (-1 <= b) & (b <= 1)]`. Along the way, you can also learn to use the numpy (recarrays)[http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html], which may make it easier to maintain a data structure like you have here.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing columns of data, store a list of rows.

Instead of storing all the columns, then picking desired columns, then filtering for desired rows, you can combined the operations:

```
def file_to_rows(fname, line_to_row=None, row_filter=None, skip_header=False, mode="r"):
    line_to_row |= lambda line: line
    row_filter  |= lambda row:  True

    with open(fname, mode) as inf:
        for line in inf:
            row = line_to_row(line)
            if row_filter(row):
                yield row

def line_to_row_items(items):
    max_split = max(items) + 1
    def fn(line):
        row = line.split(None, max_split)
        return [row[item] for item in items]
    return fn

def row_filter(row):
    return (
             0. <= row[0] <= 100.
        and -1. <= row[1] <=   1.
    )

data = list(file_to_rows(
    "mydata.txt",
    line_to_row_items([0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 15, 18, 21]),   # which columns to keep
    skip_header = True
))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I think this is perhaps more complicated than I'm looking for. I've decided to go back and use a numpy array.